# simple DSL in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dsl

I would like to make a DSL in Ruby, where I will can using simple commands do something.  For example "GO PRINT 10 *"   will print 10 stars 
or "GO PRINT 5 &" will print 5 ampersand. Anyone know good tutorials ?
I heard about the gem docile It is worthy of attention?

Comment: I'd suggest learning the basics of writing DSLs yourself first. Otherwise Docile might become a magic black box for you which could be hard to understand.

Comment: The book _Design Patterns in Ruby by Russ Olsen_ has a chapter on DSLs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tutorials for writing DSL in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936146/tutorials-for-writing-dsl-in-ruby)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links relevant to what you want to do:

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/writing-a-domain-specific-language-in-ruby
[Tutorials for writing DSL in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4936146/2636454)
https://www.leighhalliday.com/creating-ruby-dsl

If you want a *very* flexible DSL (i.e., one in which you can't tell that it's actually Ruby, which sounds like what you want), I'd suggest learning a language such as [Racket](https://racket-lang.org) which is very well-geared towards creating all sorts of languages, e.g., [a brainf*ck clone](http://www.hashcollision.org/brainfudge/), [a stack-based calculator](http://beautifulracket.com/stacker/), [these](http://beautifulracket.com/appendix/domain-specific-languages.html#racket-implemented-dsls), and [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racket_features#Language_Extensions).